# What does the phrase "Tubular Journey" mean here?

Tags: phrases, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning

Please help me figure out the meaning of the phrase "tubular journey" that is used as a title of a running game's description.

I know the lexical meaning of the word ["tubular](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/tubular)", but it doesn't seem to fit here.

The main character continuously runs in a city that reminds one of 70's decade. Does the word "tubular" have a connection to that decade?

Comment: Was your question not answered by checking a dictionary? Please include the research you’ve done.

Comment: *"tubular"* was 70/80s surfer/California slang for *"awesome"*.  [See this web page](https://www.dictionary.com/e/s/80s-words/#tubular). Does the city resemble LA?

Comment: @PeterShor that should be an answer.  A few of us are old enough to remember that.

Comment: @PeterShor Your suggestion makes perfect in the given context. I am not sure if the city resembles LA.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*"Tubular"* was originally surfer slang in the 1970s, meaning *"awesome"*. It later spread more broadly among young people in California in the 1980s, and then became hopelessly passé.

It's discussed on [this web page](https://www.dictionary.com/e/s/80s-words/#tubular) of 80s slang.

It seems quite likely this is the meaning of *tubular journey* the OP is asking about, especially if the city in the game at all resembles LA in the 1970s.

Comment: So _not_ a trip on the London Underground.

Comment: tubular in surfing means surfing the inner surface of the barrel,or tube, of a wave. I know because I am a surfer. But yes, the adjective is similar to gnarly, i.e., awesome. I dunno the game mentioned here but the canyons of a city can be like a tube.

Comment: I have no recollection of actually experiencing this term in use, but I think it may have lingered on a bit longer than the ‘80s. It’s used by Jay and Ernie in _Hocus Pocus_ (1993), and while those two are sort of the Beavis and Butthead of the film, I don’t think their slang would have been hopelessly passé – just slightly on its way out.